# reverse engineering a switch statement in C from x86 assembly

Tags: c, x86, reverse-engineering

I have to reverse engineer a switch statement in C from assembly. When i compile using the -S flag to get the assembly code from to C i wrote, it is incorrect. Any insight as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

This is the assembly

```
.file "switch_prob-soln.c"
.text
.globl switch_prob
.type switch_prob, @function
switch_prob:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
subq $50, %rsi
cmpq $5, %rsi
ja .L2
jmp *.L7(,%rsi,8)
.section .rodata
.align 8
.align 4
.L7:
.quad .L3
.quad .L2
.quad .L3
.quad .L4
.quad .L5
.quad .L6
.text
.L3:
leaq 0(,%rdi,4), %rax 
ret
.L4:
movq %rdi, %rax
sarq $2, %rax
ret
.L5:
leaq (%rdi,%rdi,2), %rdi
.L6:
imulq %rdi, %rdi
.L2:
leaq 10(%rdi), %rax
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
.size switch_prob, .-switch_prob
.ident "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3"
.section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

this is the C I wrote

```
  long switch_prob(long x, long n){
    long result = x; 
    switch(n){

      case 50:  
      case 51:
      result + 4; 
      break; 

      case 52:
      result >> 2; 
      break; 

      case 53:
      result + result + 2; 

      merge: 
      result * result
      break;

      default:
      result * 10;
      break;
   }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Besides the fact that `long result - x;` doesn't mean anything, and none of your computations have any side effects, you also have a function defined within a function, which is not C.

Comment: *"...it is incorrect."* How? You haven't explained what the actual problem is.

Comment: You should compile your C code as `gcc -Wall -S -O -fverbose-asm` and you need to improve the code till you get no warnings. Notice that `result*10;` (the 4th to last line) has no observable side-effect so is likely to be optimized and removed. Perhaps you mean `return result * 10;`  instead, but that is only  a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just following the logic of the assembly code, I'm guessing something like:

```
int switch_prob(int x, int n) {
    int result = x; 

    switch (n - 50) {

        case 0:  
        case 2:
            result += 4; 
            break; 

        case 3:
            result >>= 2; 
            break; 

        case 4:
            result += 2; 

        case 5: 
            result *= result;
            break;

        default:
            result += 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

One way you could test your solution is to write a driver program like:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int switch_prob(int x, int n);


int main() {

    printf("%d\n", switch_prob(1, 54));

    return 0;
}
```

And then compile the assembly code, if it's compatible with your system, with your driver:

```
gcc -Wall test.c switch_prob-soln.s
```

Then edit your test.c file changing the arguments to `switch_prob()` to see if your assumptions hold.  I'm guessing the jump table tells us a bit about the cases:

```
.quad .L3 # case 0: addition (LEA)
.quad .L2 # default: (no case 1:) addition (LEA)
.quad .L3 # case 2: is case 0: again
.quad .L4 # case 3: right shift (SAR)
.quad .L5 # case 4: addition (LEA)
.quad .L6 # case 5: multiplication (IMUL)
```

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! I'll definitely try this out

Comment: one last question, I know lea can be used for operations, as it was here, but I also read it is essentially a way to move something from one index to another, such as in an array, or am I interpreting it wrong? (sorry i'm very new to assembly and the logical leap from OO is hard for me).